# Why does the light_manager of MlabSceneModel not get set?

Tags: python, mayavi

I am using Mayavi for a 3D visualization with TraitsUI. The `scene` is a trait of the type MlabSceneModel. I want to change the lighting and trying to access `scene.light_manager` in a function called on the `activated` event. However, `scene.light_manager` is always `None`.

Using `mlab.figure()` to creates a scene which has a light manager, but as I want the scene to be integrated in the UI and not in an additional window this is no option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question which threw me for a loop at first.

Looking at the tvtk source, the light manager is added to the scene when the interactor is generated, which occurs after scene activation.  Furthermore, the first thing I tried, which was to listen to `'scene:light_manager'` doesn't work because the light manager is a `Property` trait that doesn't directly change.  That said, if you listen to the object itself, which is referred to by the property, it will trigger a notification on creation.  In other words, do this:

```
class Application(HasTraits):
  scene=Instance(MlabSceneModel,())

  ...

  @on_trait_change('scene:scene_editor:light_manager')
  def muck_with_the_lights(self):
    print self.scene.light_manager
```

Comment: By the way, since you mention `mlab.figure`, what `mlab.figure` does is set the current figure.  This happens to create a new scene if there isn't one, but it is possible to set the figure a la `fig=mlab.figure(figure=self.scene.mayavi_scene,bgcolor='yellow')` or something of this sort.  This isn't related to the problem at hand.